# Convex Mixed-Integer for Non-Rigid Point Cloud Alignment

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, alignment, point-clouds, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to approach non-rigid alignment using Convex Mixed-Integer Algorithm, but I am new to computer vision. Does anyone know some sample code that is similar - so that I can use that as a reference?

The algorithm is based on this research paper:
[MINA: Convex Mixed-Integer Programming for Non-Rigid Shape Alignment](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/mina-convex-mixed-integer-programming-for-non)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for showing interest in our work.

We model the constrained optimization problem in [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) with the help of [YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/) library and solve it using [MOSEK](https://www.mosek.com/).